# How do I plot various values of the partial sums for a function with 2 variables?

Tags: plotting, summation

This is what I have tried so far.

I have a function defined as the below:

```
Multifactorial[n_, k_] := Abs[Apply[Times, Range[-n, -1, k]]]
s[i_] := Sum[1/Multifactorial[n, 1], {n, 1, i}]
ListPlot[Table[{i, s[i]}, {i, 1, 100}]]
```

Which results in the following plot of the partial sums of Multifactorial[n,1] .
[image: ListPlot]

I managed to display the partial sums when its just a single variable function (i.e. me manually inputting the argument for k).

However what I am trying to achieve is display as one plot (with different colours and a legend) the partial sums of MultiFactorial[n,1] through to MultiFactorial[n,10]. I was not able to define this as I don't know the syntax well enough.

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListPlot[Table[Sum[1/Multifactorial[n, j], {n, 1, i}], {j, 1, 10}, {i, 1, 100}],
 PlotLegends ->  PointLegend[Automatic, PromptForm[j, #] & /@ Range[10], 
    LegendMarkers -> {Graphics[Disk[]], 6}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks thats perfect and simple. I was sure I must have been making a syntax error.